# My PostgreSQL auto inserts many space characters after the value of a field

Tags: postgresql

When I insert data in PostgreSQL, it is auto inserting many spaces after the value of the field.

I tired to fix it, but I can't find anything

[image]

For example: I want to insert value 'John' in column 'Name'. It inserts spaces after John.

```
->> 'John______________________________________________________________'
```

Comment: You have a CHAR field, instead of a VARCHAR.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`character` is an awful data type that should not be used. This is just one of the reasons. See [character types - postgresql manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html).

Change those fields to `text` or to `varchar(n)`. `text` with a `check` constraint on length where one is required is usually the best option.

```
ALTER TABLE thetable ALTER COLUMN colname TYPE text;
```

BTW, it's easier to answer your questions if you post the SQL and - preferably - the output of running that SQL in `psql`, which produces copy-and-pasteable plain text output.